# Delete an object or polygon that has been selected in a layer using the Graphical Modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, delete

I wish to create a model in QGIS 3, that can delete a specific polygon that has been selected in a layer. Is it possible to do this? I go through a few different locations in a day and I don't wish to waste time manually deleting that polygon every time I open up a new location. I already have a model that selects the polygon via longitude and latitude, and I really just wish to add an algorithm on top of that, if that isn't possible create a new model entirely.

Comment: You can write your own processing tool that deletes all selected features. After that you can use your processing tool like other tools and intergrate it in a model. That needs to know python and how to write a processing tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using basically two steps.

First use the **save selected features**, so QGIS will create a copy of the selected features.

After that, use **extract by location** between the original entry and the features selected with the **disjoint** premise.

Depending on how your file is, you may need another type of comparison, using a **join by attributes** field is also possible, just save the **Unjoinable Features output**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the selected polygons are a different entity in the attribute table you can erase them all together.
First you need to choose the those polygon, so they will be selected in the attribute table.

[image]

Then, once the layer is in editing mode you can erase all the marked polygons at once with the "Delete Selected" button. It is located near the "Editing Mode" button and its icon is a red garbage can.

[image]